# Which method(in Android Life Cycle) is called when "ANR(Application Not Responding)" happens in Android?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, crash-reports, activity-lifecycle, android-anr-dialog

Hope you you all doing well!

I'm having issues when ANR does happen. I want to handle ANR, instead of that horror app crash want show my custom alert message saying "An error occurred."(like: Google Play Music App) with "Ok" button.

Please provide answer/comment/suggestions any.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: you can't catch or handle it. You have to fix your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can't catch an ANR, unlike exceptions that occur within your process's VM, ANR is generated by a system watchdog, outside your VM

Google privides info on that : [External link](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)